# Why are all of the arrays deleting an element in this set instead of the one being referenced?

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

My code:

```
uniformPieces3 = ['company1_hat', 'company1_glasses', 'company2_hat']
uniformSet3 = ['hat', 'glasses']


f1 = function(uniformSet, uniformPieces) {

uniformPieces.sort();
let arr1 = []
for (i = 0; i < uniformPieces.length; i++){
    arr1[i] = uniformPieces[i].substr(0, uniformPieces[i].indexOf('_'))
}
let hold = new Set(arr1);
let missingPieces = new Set
hold.forEach(element => missingPieces[element] = uniformSet);



uniformPieces.forEach(e=>{
  let t = e.split('_');
  if(missingPieces.hasOwnProperty(t[0])){
    var index = missingPieces[t[0]].indexOf(t[1]);

    if (index !== -1) {
      console.log(t[0])
      missingPieces[t[0]].splice(index, 1);
     
    }

  }
  });

  console.log(missingPieces)

}

f1(uniformSet3, uniformPieces3);
```

When I call `splice()` on misingPieces, it is deleting an element in every array rather than the specific the array within the set. For example:

```
Set(0) {
  company1: [ 'hat', 'glasses' ],
  company2: [ 'hat', 'glasses' ]}
```

Then `missingPieces[t[0]].splice(index, 1)` is called, which should delete one element, but instead yields:

```
Set(0) { company1: [ 'hat' ], company2: [ 'hat' ] }
```

Thus deleting the element from all arrays in the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think at a quick read over, you are storing the same reference (`uniformSet`) and so when you splice one, it splices all (because they are all actually the same referrence)

try copying `uniformSet` instead of assigning it directly

```
  hold.forEach(element => missingPieces[element] = [...uniformSet]);
```

(I didn't test this)

Answer (score 0):

Non-primitive data types are [passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104500/16806649). If you would like to create a copy instead of creating another variable for the same reference, you need to clone/copy all values. If you use the second line here, `my_object` and `another_variable_for_same_reference` refer to the same object.

```
let my_object = {};
let another_variable_for_same_reference = my_object;
let object_with_copied_values = {...my_object};
```